# How to keep checkbox active after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I try making a dark-theme for my website and I used a checkbox for this to work. I've written some JS code and after refresh I want the check status to remain the same(if dark-theme was enabled before refresh it should remain the same). I tried using localStorage but didn't manage to accomplish anything by that. Any ideas?

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
const body = document.body;

toggle.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const isChecked = e.target.checked;

  if (isChecked) {
    localStorage.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
  } else {
    body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" autocomplete="off" />
  <label for="toggle"></label>
  <h4 class="credits" id="credits">&#169; Irimia Nicolae & Zar&#259; Mihnea Tudor</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `localStorage.body`? I was going to suggest you to use `localStorage` but it seems you used it in the wrong way

Comment: Well const body represents the body of my html. If I remove the localStorage from there my code runs ok, but on refresh is jumps back to the value of non checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
const body = document.body;

const toggleTheme = () => {
  const isChecked = toggle.checked;
  body.classList.toggle('dark-theme',isChecked);
  localStorage.setItem('theme',isChecked ? 'dark-theme' : ''); // how to store
};

toggle.checked = localStorage.getItem('theme'); // how to read - check if found
toggle.addEventListener('input', toggleTheme); // run when clicking
toggleTheme(); // initialise on load
```